# Is my "hidden" page secured?

Tags: joomla-2.5, security

I want to create a page which someone can view only if he is registered and granted access to.

For granting access to a user for i use a row in the #__users table named `activated2`.

So i created a view file inside a component and my `view.html.php` file is like that:

```
class IpropertyViewVtourpaketa extends JView
{
  function display($tpl = null)
  {   
                 $user = JFactory::getUser();

                 if (!$user) {

                  header('Location:index.php?msgvtour=You need to register and get activated');

                }
                else {
                 $db= JFactory::getDBO();
                 $query='SELECT activated2 from `#__users` where id='.$user->id;

                 $db->setQuery($query);
                 $pro=$db->loadResult();

                 if ($pro==0) {

                     header('Location: index.php?msgvtour=You need to get activated');
                 }else {

                // Display the view
                parent::display($tpl);
              }
            }
        }
}
?>
```

So what im doing is : check if he is registered, if not redirect him . Then check if he is activated, If not redirect him. Else redirect to the view where he can see the page.
This is working really nice altough what i wanted to know is:

How safe is this way i use?
Could this be easily hacked or bypassed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things I would change:

- You should not put your database queries in this file. Joomla uses MVC, therefore your queries should be put in a function, in the model.
- Don't use PHP's default `header()` function. Instead make full use of the [Joomla API for redirecting](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JApplication.html#method_redirect)
- Rather than adding your own column (activated2) to the `#__users` table which is a bad idea, I'd suggest you make full use of [Joomla's ACL Management](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List) for your component.
- For the database query, I'd suggest using Joomla's methods rather than writing it in plain SQL. [Here here for more information](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

Hope this helps

Comment: i use `$app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php', false));` as in API, altough i get redirected @ `index.php?option=com_iproperty` any idea on whats wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

No, your code is not right.

- JFactory::getUser() always returns a user object. If user is a guest, $user->id == 0 or better ($user->guest)
- In `#__users` table, there is no user id 0
- index.php?msgvtour does not seem to belong to Joomla world
- Instead of "header('Location:...", it is better to work with Joomla API (check )

For example, from components/com_users/views/profile/view.html.php:

```
/**
 * Execute and display a template script.
 *
 * @param   string  $tpl  The name of the template file to parse; automatically searches through the template paths.
 *
 * @return  mixed   A string if successful, otherwise a Error object.
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    ....
    // View also takes responsibility for checking if the user logged in with remember me.
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $cookieLogin = $user->get('cookieLogin');

    if (!empty($cookieLogin))
    {
        // If so, the user must login to edit the password and other data.
        // What should happen here? Should we force a logout which destroys the cookies?
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_MUST_LOGIN'), 'message');
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));

        return false;
    }

    ....

    return parent::display($tpl);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if ($user->id == 0) ` I would use `if ($user->guest)` :-)

Comment: Right! I always forget it